# Why doesn't ByteBuffer preserve index for putDouble and getDouble?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I'm having difficulty understanding the semantics of `ByteBuffer` in the following scenario:

```
int sizeOfDouble = 8;
int numberOfDoubles = 4;
ByteBuffer testBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(sizeOfDouble*numberOfDoubles);

testBuf.putDouble(0, 1.0);
testBuf.putDouble(1, 2.0);
testBuf.putDouble(2, 3.0);
testBuf.putDouble(3, 4.0);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDoubles; ++i) {
    System.out.println("testBuf[" + i + "]: " + testBuf.getDouble(i));
}
```

I expected to see the values I had just put into the `ByteBuffer` to be printed to the screen. Instead, I get this output:

```
testBuf[0]: 4.959404759574682E-4
testBuf[1]: 32.50048828125
testBuf[2]: 32.125
testBuf[3]: 4.0
```

The value at the third index seems to match what I expect: 4.0. But why aren't the values and indices 0, 1, and 2 matching up with the values I inserted (1.0, 2.0, and 3.0, respectively)?

I suspect I misunderstand something about how `ByteBuffer` works, but I haven't been able to find it in the javadoc.

Comment: I haven't worked with `ByteBuffer` yet, but don't you have to access the indices in multiples of 8? After all, a `double` is 8 bytes big. E.g.: `testBuf.putDouble(0, 1.0);
testBuf.putDouble(8, 2.0);
testBuf.putDouble(16, 3.0);
testBuf.putDouble(24, 4.0);`. The same goes for `getDouble` then.

Answer (score 5):

This is because your code treats index as an index in an array of `double`s. The initial write completes successfully; then the second one writes over its bytes except the first one; the third write overwrites the bytes again, and so on. The results of the last write don't get written over, so `4.0` comes out intact.

The first argument represents an index into the array of bytes inside the buffer, so you need to multiply it by `sizeOfDouble`:

```
testBuf.putDouble(0*sizeOfDouble, 1.0);
testBuf.putDouble(1*sizeOfDouble, 2.0);
testBuf.putDouble(2*sizeOfDouble, 3.0);
testBuf.putDouble(3*sizeOfDouble, 4.0);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDoubles; ++i) {
    System.out.println("testBuf[" + i + "]: " + testBuf.getDouble(sizeOfDouble*i));
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/c1UciW)

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense. And it also makes sense that I was getting the "correct" value for the last index I added. Beautiful!

Comment: Of course, since you're only working with doubles, you could just use a [`DoubleBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html) instead, so the index is in doubles, not bytes.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument of `putDouble()` is an index of a byte and not an index of a double. So the doubles you put are overlapping; the fourth is written last, so it is preserved, but the previous ones are corrupted.

To get what you want, you need to multiply the index by `Double.BYTES` both when you write and read them.

The following works as expected:

```
int numberOfDoubles = 4;
ByteBuffer testBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Double.BYTES*numberOfDoubles);

testBuf.putDouble(0, 1.0);
testBuf.putDouble(Double.BYTES, 2.0);
testBuf.putDouble(Double.BYTES * 2, 3.0);
testBuf.putDouble(Double.BYTES * 3, 4.0);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDoubles; ++i) {
    System.out.println("testBuf[" + i + "]: " + testBuf.getDouble(i * Double.BYTES));
}
```

Comment: Or instead of multiplying by 8, use `Double.BYTES` to get the bytes on your platform.  (Which is probably 8, but why introduce new constants?)

Comment: Thanks! I could only select one answer for this question, but your explanation is also right on. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @markspace Thanks for noting this, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only working with `double` values, you could use a [`DoubleBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html) instead:

```
int numberOfDoubles = 4;
DoubleBuffer testBuf = DoubleBuffer.allocate(numberOfDoubles);

testBuf.put(0, 1.0);
testBuf.put(1, 2.0);
testBuf.put(2, 3.0);
testBuf.put(3, 4.0);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDoubles; ++i) {
    System.out.println("testBuf[" + i + "]: " + testBuf.get(i));
}
```

Or you could wrap the `ByteBuffer` with a `DoubleBuffer`:

```
int sizeOfDouble = Double.BYTES;
int numberOfDoubles = 4;
ByteBuffer testBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(sizeOfDouble*numberOfDoubles);
DoubleBuffer dblBuf = testBuf.asDoubleBuffer();

dblBuf.put(0, 1.0);
dblBuf.put(1, 2.0);
dblBuf.put(2, 3.0);
dblBuf.put(3, 4.0);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDoubles; ++i) {
    System.out.println("dblBuf[" + i + "]: " + dblBuf.get(i));
}
for (int i = 0; i < testBuf.limit(); ++i) {
    System.out.println("testBuf[" + i + "]: " + testBuf.get(i));
}
```

*Output*

```
dblBuf[0]: 1.0
dblBuf[1]: 2.0
dblBuf[2]: 3.0
dblBuf[3]: 4.0
testBuf[0]: 63
testBuf[1]: -16
testBuf[2]: 0
testBuf[3]: 0
testBuf[4]: 0
testBuf[5]: 0
testBuf[6]: 0
testBuf[7]: 0
testBuf[8]: 64
testBuf[9]: 0
testBuf[10]: 0
testBuf[11]: 0
testBuf[12]: 0
testBuf[13]: 0
testBuf[14]: 0
testBuf[15]: 0
testBuf[16]: 64
testBuf[17]: 8
testBuf[18]: 0
testBuf[19]: 0
testBuf[20]: 0
testBuf[21]: 0
testBuf[22]: 0
testBuf[23]: 0
testBuf[24]: 64
testBuf[25]: 16
testBuf[26]: 0
testBuf[27]: 0
testBuf[28]: 0
testBuf[29]: 0
testBuf[30]: 0
testBuf[31]: 0
```